# Memory is never released potential leak of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Just ran `analyze` on my app and it threw up this memory error and pointed to the `return` line in the following code:

```
int                 mgmtInfoBase[6];
char                *msgBuffer = NULL;
size_t              length;
unsigned char       macAddress[6];
struct if_msghdr    *interfaceMsgStruct;
struct sockaddr_dl  *socketStruct;
NSString            *errorFlag = NULL;

mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;        // Request network subsystem
mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       // Routing table info
mgmtInfoBase[2] = 0;
mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        // Request link layer information
mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  // Request all configured interfaces

if ((mgmtInfoBase[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0)
    errorFlag = @"if_nametoindex failure";
else
{
    if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
        errorFlag = @"sysctl mgmtInfoBase failure";
    else
    {
        if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
            errorFlag = @"buffer allocation failure";
        else
        {
            if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, msgBuffer, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
                errorFlag = @"sysctl msgBuffer failure";
        }
    }
}

if (errorFlag != NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag);        
    return errorFlag;                  // this line gives the memory leak warning
}
```

I don't know much `C` and was hoping someone could tell what's going on here.

Comment: For ever `malloc()`-type call, there better be a *reachable* `free()` *somewhere* to return it back to the implementation when finished. If you don't have a reachable `free()`, you have a leak. It really is that simple. (`realloc()` with a zero-size not withstanding).

Comment: +1 and thanks for the explanation. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: In the event, that `malloc(length)` works fine but the following `sysctl(...)` returns a negative value, then `msgbuffer` will not be released/freed. So there may be really a memory leak, it is not just analyzer telling you there could be one.

Comment: @HermannKlecker: Thanks & +1. I'm learning here. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to free msgBuffer

```
 if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
```

may be you can do it before just before return

```
if (errorFlag != NULL)
{
    free (msgBuffer); // Free here
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag); 
    return errorFlag;                  // this line gives the memory leak warning
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That appears to have solved it. =) I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows.

Answer (score 4):

You are not `free` ing buffer `msgBuffer` allocated in this line:

```
if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
```